# Button overlapping EditText when keyboard is open

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-softkeyboard, android-constraintlayout

I have the following ConstraintLayout in my Android application:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/white">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/image_icon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/icon"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          />

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/instructions"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
          android:text="@string/instruction"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/support_ic"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/call_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/phone"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/instructions"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />


      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/message_content"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:lines="8"
          android:hint="@string/support_message_hint"
          android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint"
          android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
          android:background="@color/background_gray"
          android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
          android:textColor="@color/black"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/send_button"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          android:gravity="top|left"
          app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
           />

        <Button
          android:id="@+id/send_button"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/support_send"
          android:background="@color/button_blue"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I open the keyboard, the view adjusts and the bottom two widgets (the button and the editText) move with the keyboard.  My problem however, is that whenever this happens, the @id/call_button Button lays on top of the editText.  I do not want this. I want the editText to overlay the button when the keyboard is open.

Is there any way to make the editText take precedent when overlapping other widgets in this scenario? I tried adding `editText.bringToFront()` in my onCreate method, but that didn't do anything.

Also, I am trying to avoid nesting the bottom two widgets (the button and the editText) inside of their own layout.  I want them all to remain in the same ConstraintLayout.  Thank you for the help ahead of time.

[image: keyboard open image]

[image: keyboard closed image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Yeah just give me a second

Comment: okay i added them

Answer (score 1):

I added `android:elevation="4dp"` to the editText's xml and it worked.

Comment: you can reorder the code to put the editText section code bellow the Button code, I think it will be better than using the elevation, because the elevation is not supported in android < 21, and you have affect the z-access of the component witch may make another problem in the future in case you have any request changes on the design. 
in addition, it's enough to set the elevation 1dp.

Comment: No I tried reordering the code already and it didn't work. Also I did not get any warnings for this in the xml, and I tested on an Api 19 device and it worked (Could have something to do with ConstraintLayout?)

Answer (score 1):

Material Design guidelines specify that `Button`s use **elevation** in both their pressed (8dp elevation) and upressed (2dp elevation) states. https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android

Which view you see when two are stacked on top of each other *at the same elevation* is dependent on the ordering of those views in your layout (e.g. why you expected the views written later to overlay the views written earlier), but elevation takes precedence over this.

As you've found, you can add elevation to your other views to make them "higher" than your button, but this is a bit ugly and might have some unwanted side-effects. I think a better choice would be to set the manifest attribute [`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)  on your activity. This will cause your activity's view to slide up when the keyboard opens, rather than resizing.

Comment: Another option could be to simply use `TextView` instead of `Button` for that one component.